# How to change multi-line text color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of a block of text on mouseover, but only got as far as the text changing if you scroll over the top border of the text.

http://angelamiller.net/archives/test/v3/

I am testing the first block of text on the top left corner, "Thesewordshelptoshapeme".

using

```
.typoBox div.l3_1 ul:hover {
  color:red;
 }
```

What I want to do eventually, is when a user rolls over a block of text and clicks the text, I can then target the other blocks of text (they are all in separate divs) with jQuery or similar to hide those divs and reveal a hidden div which would contain descriptive text about that block of text.

I am not worried about this working on ie 6, but currently am on my mac and have only tried firefox and chrome at this point.

I would be willing to add anchors if it would help.

In my google search the closest thing I could find was a jQuery solution but didn't work:

```
<script>
  $("div.l3_1 ul").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show what your html mark up looks like, what you're *targeting* with your jQuery?

Comment: <div class="l3_1"> 
   <ul> 
    <li>thesewo</li> 
    <li>rdshel</li> 
    <li>ptosha</li> 
    <li>peme</li> 
   </ul> 
  </div>

Comment: I've also tried to use one list element and add breaks in one string of text where I want the next line to start and that didn't work either.  <li>thesewo<br />rdshel<br />ptosha<br />peme</li>

Comment: to play: http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/eL5xt/

Comment: Are the blocks of text consistently contained within `li` elements?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NWjFp/ I'm not sure of the specs but this can give a starting point, BTW: nice work I like a lot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your z-indexing. When I click on something with firebug, it gives me the top `div.tw`. This is true, because you manually put the z-index of that on top. So by means of hitTesting, this is correct. Problem is, I think it is impossible to have some not be hittested. So it has nothing to do with your css. Remove the tw div, or its indexing and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problems with the selectors, not the rules.  If you add `display: none` to the `div.13_1 ul {` rule, you'll see that it has no effect. That's as far as I've gotten.